# executing an action in a different view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, ibaction

In my application, I am trying to create a button, with a button. My code right now is as follows:

```
- (IBAction)doneTextField:(id)sender {

    YourShortcutsViewController *YSVC2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];
    YSVC2.stringFromTextField = self.textField.text;
    [self presentViewController:YSVC2 animated:YES completion:nil];

    {
        UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

        btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50);
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(newButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [btn setTitle:@"FaceTime" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.view addSubview:btn];

    }
}
```

this works, but I need the button that is being added to add in a different view controller, not the view controller that the code is in.
How would I do this??
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a function to add the button in the new view controller:

In YourShortcutsViewController.h:

```
-(void)addFaceTimeButton:(UIButton*);
```

In YourShortcutsViewController.m:

```
-(void)addFaceTimeButton:(UIButton*){
    [self.view addSubview:btn];
}
```

And then change your code to:

```
- (IBAction)doneTextField:(id)sender {

    YourShortcutsViewController *YSVC2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];
    YSVC2.stringFromTextField = self.textField.text;
    [self presentViewController:YSVC2 animated:YES completion:nil];

    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50);
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(newButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btn setTitle:@"FaceTime" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [YSVC2 addFaceTimeButton:btn];

}
```